# ArrayList, LinkedList (метод get())

Tags: java

Можете пожалуйста пошагово объяснить, как будет происходить get(5) для списка из 10 элементов в ArrayList и в LinkedList.

```
 ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
        a.add("Test");
        a.add(123);
        a.add(true);
        a.add(242.42);
        System.out.println(a.get(1));

        LinkedList b = new LinkedList();
        b.add("Test");
        b.add(123);
        b.add(true);
        b.add(242.42);
        System.out.println(b.get(1));
```

Что так, что так я получил одинаковый результат. Но на собеседовании это часто спрашивают.

Comment: учитесь пользоваться дебагером. пригодиться.

Comment: вы знаете, чем массив отличается от связанного списка?

Comment: У ArrayList реализация через массив, поэтому для получения элемента по индексу он будет у внутреннего массива запрошен (типа `_data[i]`), а у LinkedList реализация через связанный список по ней каждый элемент имеет связь с следующим элементом и чтобы получить элемент, например, в середине нужно будет пройтись по всем элементам через связь

Comment: @gil9red спасибо большое, можете закинуть в ответ, я приму

Comment: @MikeMclaren, у вас уже есть ответ с этой же информацией :)

Answer (score 2):

В ArrayList ты просто вернешь элемент который стоит во внутреннем массиве в этой позиции.
В LinkedList будет произведен цикл который выдаст тебе содержимое узла с этим индексом